# javascript - find and click a button

Tags: javascript

I'd like to complete an autologin script, but I need to find and click a button without ID or Name.

```
<input type="submit" class="recaptcha-submit btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-primary" value="Přihlaste se">
```

How can I find such element using javascript?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: use `document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-submit")` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `document.getElementsByClassName` method to search by class name.

From your piece of code it seems that `recaptcha-submit` would be unique to that input, so you can search by it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('recaptcha-submit')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the button is a `submit` button, one option is to submit the form rather than clicking the submit button. If your form is called `myForm`, you can try this:

```
document.forms['myForm'].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `JQuery` to call `trigger()` on `click` event to achieve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //this is just to verify that click works
  $('.recaptcha-submit.btn.btn-lg.btn-fill.btn-primary').click(function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  });

  $('.recaptcha-submit.btn.btn-lg.btn-fill.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="recaptcha-submit btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-primary" value="Přihlaste se">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks H77 for working solution:

```
var loginbtn = document.querySelector("#login > form > div.form-group.button-group > input").click();
```